# Dice Roll Probability

Tags: python, probability

I am trying to find the probability of an odd number occurring in 1 single dice roll. I understand that this is 3/6=1/2 . 
Formula = Possible outcomes/ Total Outcomes = 3 possible outcomes / 6 total outcomes =1/2.
Similarly if I roll the same dice 2 times the probability = 1/2 * 1/2.
My code is not good for finding the total possible outcomes once I generate the random number. Appreciate any pointers.

```
import random
# Determine sample space or total outcomes
N = [1,2,3]
dice_max = 6
outcomes = [] 

for i in range (len(N)):
    elem = N[i]
    if elem == 1:
        sample_outcomes = elem * dice_max
    else:
        sample_outcomes = dice_max ** elem
    outcomes.append(sample_outcomes)
    #print(outcomes)
    #print(sample_outcomes)    

# Determine if the dice roll is randomly 1,3,5 
    possible_outcomes = 0
    result = random.randint(1, 6)
# Determing possible outcomes
    if result == 1 or result ==3 or result ==5:
        possible_outcomes +=1
    print (possible_outcomes)
```

Comment: what is the specific problem you are having? saying the code is "not good" is not much to go on. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: minor tip:
`if result == 1 or result ==3 or result ==5` can be written as `if result in (1, 3, 5)`
or as `if result % 2 == 1`

Comment: another minor tip: instead of writing your loop as `for i in range(len(N)):`, you can just write `for n in N:`. Then, instead of accessing a member of N like this: `elem = N[i]` you can just  use `elem = n` (and really, `elem` is not necessary at all)

Comment: Thanks , I should have been more explicit. How do I identify the total possible outcomes in single dice roll in this case odd numbers so its 3 possible outcomes ? Once I have that I can divide by total outcomes which is 6 . Hence the probability is 1/2.

Comment: @ESLearner Are you looking to find this given the number of rolls? (e.g., I can roll up to 3 times, what's the chance I can roll an odd number?)